# ApplyForce in box2dweb.js

Tags: javascript, box2d, box2dweb

I am trying to apply a force to a body I created. But i cant seem to get it right. This is the body I am creating:

```
     //create some objects
      var fixDef2 = new b2FixtureDef;
     fixDef2.density = 1.0;
     fixDef2.friction = 0.5;
     fixDef2.restitution = 0.2;
      var bodyDef2 = new b2BodyDef;
     bodyDef2.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;


           fixDef2.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
           fixDef2.shape.SetAsBox(
                 50/30 + 0.1 //half width
              ,  6/30 + 0.1 //half height
           );
        bodyDef2.position.x = Math.random() * 10;
        bodyDef2.position.y = Math.random() * 10;
        bodyDef2.fixedRotation = true;
        var body=world.CreateBody(bodyDef2);
        body.CreateFixture(fixDef2);
```

I want to apply a force to make the body move to the left.
Currently I am trying this:

```
body.ApplyForce( direction , body.GetPosition() );
```

Which is not doing anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and what do you use for direction?

Comment: var direction = b2Vec2(-5,0);

Comment: have you tried to increase the force?

Comment: I have found the cause, my own stupidity. var direction = new b2Vec2(-5,0); Forgot the new